# How to sort multiple strings inside list alphabetically ascending in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'd like to write a function which can return the sorted strings inside a list by alphabetically ascending. Like it should turn

```
["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"]
```

into

```
["apple banana", "cat dog elephant"].
```

I tried:

```
def apply_to_list(string_list):
   new = []
   for i in [0,len(string_list)-1]:
    data = sorted(string_list[i])
    new = data.append
    print(new)
    return new
```

It turned out to be wrong.
I know how to sort if the list is simple, I can do:

```
def sort_words(string):
    words = [word.lower() for word in string.split()]
    words.sort()
    for word in words:
    print(word)
    return
```

However, when it comes to several strings inside each of the attribute of a list, my approach failed.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each string, you can use `str.split` to get individual words + `sorted` to sort the words + `join` to join back the words into a single string in a list comprehension:

```
[' '.join(sorted(x.split())) for x in lst]
```

Output:

```
['apple banana', 'cat dog elephant']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"] 

s = [' '.join(sorted(word.split(' '))) for word in words]
print(s)

#['apple banana', 'cat dog elephant']
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to sort all the strings in the list, you could use a list comprehension over the items inside your list.

For any item, which is the string you want to sort, `split` the item and obtain a list of its words. Then use `sorted` to obtain a sorted version of this list.
Finally use `join` with `" "` to rebuild a string with all its substrings sorted:

```
foo = ["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"] 

def apply_to_list(myList):
    return [ ' '.join(sorted(item.split())) for item in myList ]
    
print(apply_to_list(foo))
```

Which outputs:

```
['apple banana', 'cat dog elephant']
```

This being said, your function:

```
def apply_to_list(string_list):
   new = []
   for i in [0,len(string_list)-1]:
    data = sorted(string_list[i])
    new = data.append
    print(new)
    return new
```

has some issues.

1. The indentation is not uniform.
2. `string_list` is an iterable. You should iterate directly over it, without using indexing.
3. `string_list[i]` is a string. You should apply `split` before `sorted`. For example, if you have `my_string="banana apple"` and apply `sorted` directly, you obtain

   ```
   [' ', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'p', 'p']
   ```
4. Considering the previous issue, the way you use `append` is not correct. `append` is a list method and it's called this way

   ```
   list_to_which_append.append(element_to_append)
   ```

Moreover, you don't call the method, so in your code, `new` is `<built-in method append of list object at 0x7fba704d4b80>` (the address is indicative and may vary).

If you want to correct that function, the code is:

```
def apply_to_list(string_list):
    new = []
    for item in string_list:
        data = sorted(item.split())
        new.append(' '.join(data))
    return new
```